# Is it possible to use Apple Push Notification Service only for local network?

Tags: notifications, services, macos, apns

I have an apsd process which stands for Apple Push Notification service daemon [man_page_on_developers.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac//documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/apsd.8.html) (it has a name `applepushserviced` on osx 10.7 and lower). Is it possible to restrict it only for local APN server without having a connection to the apple global APN server?

Answer (score 1):

Disabling the internet connection for this service would prevent you from receiving any notifications which use the Apple Push service. Restricting it to your local network would have the same effect as preventing it from connecting at all, since there is no local APN server.

Comment: so there is no setting for that configuration using the APN?

Comment: I'm not understanding what you are asking.